# Exporting/importing utility functions between React ES6 components in React-Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create a utils.js that contains all of my utility functions, which are used by many of my React components.

I try to export and import a Utilities class into my React component like this:

```
// utils. js
export default class Utilities; 


// myComponent.es6.jsx
import someFunction from 'Utilities';
```

I receive errors like these:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function)
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

How do I set up a separate utilities page that can then be imported into my React components?

I'm baffled -- thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your answer could be [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/413). Basically, I believe it's because `import` `export` and `require` are not yet fully compatible with Rails and all browsers. That's why in most applications they use Babel transpiler or common JS stuff. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks, oreoluwa! I really appreciate it.